# Reset hibernation delay from command line

Tags: command-line, cron, scripts, hibernate

My hibernation on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS works fine. But someone keeps changing its delay to never hibernate. I am tired of paying days' worth of electricity for 10 minutes usage a day.

Is there a way I can reset the hibernation delay to 20 minutes from command line?

Then I could script and crontab it... So it would put itself back at 20 minutes even if someone changes it on and on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and use the following command to know the preferred action that is set, when your system is **idle** and on **ac power**.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
'suspend'
```

you can see in my system it is set to **suspend**.

To change the value to 'hibernate' use the following command in terminal,

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type 'hibernate'
```

To know the idle timeout or delay before the preferred action, when your system is **idle** and on **ac power**.

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout
0
```

In my system the time out is never represented by `sleep-inactive-ac-timeout=0`.

To change it to 20 min (20x60=1200 sec) use the following command,

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 1200
```

Comment: This certainly did the trick! The only thing I had to change is the 20 for 1200 (I discovered setting is in seconds rather then minutes). Me and my wallet thank you. The electricity company certainly won't...

Comment: Happy to know that your problem is solved. Thanks for your comment. corrected my answer.